# Trying to create a dictionary from lines in a text file, but code keeps returning an empty dictionary?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, dictionary

I've opened a file for reading, and I want to analyze each line. If the line satisfies a condition, I want to add that line to a dictionary. But this code keeps returning an empty list! Can you point out anything that you find wrong?

```
dictionary = {}
file = open("text_file.txt", "r")

colors = ("Bright red", "Light green", "Sky blue", "Dark brown")

def read_file(file):
   for line in file:
       if line in colors:
           dictionary[line] = ''
return dictionary
file.close()
```

When I input:

```
read_file(file)
```

Instead of creating a dictionary that looks like `{'Bright red': '', 'Light green': '', 'Sky blue': '', 'Dark brown': ''}`, it returns `{}`.

The file is a text file, and it looks like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Bright red
Aliquam et magna at orci lobortis blandit.
Phasellus mattis velit auctor libero rhoncus semper.
Curabitur vitae sapien ac sem lobortis egestas.
Light green
Sed vitae augue sit amet lectus consectetur consectetur.
Sed bibendum metus vel libero porta, eu malesuada nibh mattis.
Sky blue
Dark brown
```

Not sure why each of the first words on each line are highlighted.. But that's what the text file looks like.

I'm really new to python, so please go easy on me.

Comment: `return dictionary` is what you are showing us in a function ?

Comment: I am not sure who up-voted this question. Looks like someone is using SO while sleeping

Comment: Can you show us some part of your file as well as the output that you expect

Comment: I see no function and no list here.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I totally forgot to include the function definition.

Comment: Can you show us, how does your file look like?

Comment: I have updated the question to show you what the text file looks like.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `return dictionary` - it makes no sense
2. The if statement is probably not returning True when you would expect it to. Try printing each line inside your loop - are there '\n' characters that are messing things up? Try iterating over `file.read().splitlines()` instead of `file`

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to do something like this:

```
dictionary = {}
file = open("text_file.txt", "r")

colors = ("Bright red", "Light green", "Sky blue", "Dark brown")

for line in file:
    if line[0:-1] in colors:
        dictionary[line] = ""
file.close()
```

Your line in file is `'line\n'`.

```
'line\n' != 'line'
```

Comment: Are you sure about `dictionary[line] = line` ? This line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Actually, yes it's mistake.

Comment: dictionary[line] = ''